# How to remove or edit existing JVM options in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-arguments

I want to remove specified JVM options in Tomcat by using commands. I have tried following commands but none of them were able to remove the option. For example, This one removes everything except specified one:

> tomcat\bin>tomcat8 //US//tomcat8 --JvmOptions -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

This one seems to do nothing also did not throw any error:

> tomcat\bin>tomcat8 //US//tomcat8 -JvmOptions -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this programming specific? Or are you managing a server? I ask because you might have more success with this question on ServerFault.

Comment: @SunSparc - I was trying to do that on multiple JVMs to make life little bit easier, so you can say I was trying to managing servers. :)

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: @Pixic - I have checked that doc it only talks about adding param with ++JvmOptions but it is not mentioned how we can remove added params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove/change the JVM options by editing the Winidows Registry directly.

The java setting is stored within Windows registry, in entry jvm under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun2.0\YourChosenServiceName\Parameters\Java

Please see the snapshot below.
[image: Windows registry for jvm options]

Comment: @BlueMice...I was looking for this. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score -1):

what do you mean by remove ,or you just want to change the options you've added

if you want to change jvm options , you can add some words in the head of the `catalina.bat(windows)` or `catalina.sh(linux)`

in windows: `set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m ...(your options etc)`

in linux: `JAVA_OPTS='-Xms256m -Xmx512m ...(your options etc)'`

ps: catalina.bat/sh  is in the directory of `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin`

Comment: The file `catalina.bat` is not used at all when Apache Tomcat is running as a Windows service.